# What is an "escape-hatch operation" in a Java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I was reading the Java docs and encountered [this sentence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference):

> Except for the escape-hatch operations `iterator()` and `spliterator()`, execution begins when the terminal operation is invoked, and ends when the terminal operation completes.

I am not sure what "escape-hatch operations" means. Could someone please explain this term?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) of the `stream` package:

> In almost all cases, **terminal operations are eager**, completing their
>   traversal of the data source and processing of the pipeline before
>   returning. Only the terminal operations `iterator()` and `spliterator()`
>   are not; these are provided as an "escape hatch" to enable arbitrary
>   client-controlled pipeline traversals in the event that the existing
>   operations are not sufficient to the task.

Which means that in most cases the stream traversal is complete when a terminal operation returns, but not in the case of `iterator()` and `spliterator()`: by using one of these terminal operations an `Iterator` or a `Spliterator` is returned, but the pipeline is still "open" and it will be processed as the elements are requested through the iterator. This way the **stream processing becomes lazy**, because the operations on the stream are only executed if the next element is requested.

```
Iterator<Person> iterator = persons
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> !p.getName().equals("Mike Tyson"))
    .iterator();
```

After the `iterator()` method is called, the stream is "terminated": you cannot chain more methods. But you can access the elements of the stream by calling the `next()` method of the returned iterator and the stream will start to be processed only the first time you do this. And this is true only if the `iterator()` or the`spliterator()` terminal operation is used.